# Object doesn't show vertices in edit mode - cant move faces either

Tags: edit-mode, vertices

Currently running into a very frustrating issue in 2.9.

I have an object which, if I go into edit mode, shows the wireframe and has selectable faces, BUT doesn't display any vertices. I've checked Shapekeys (don't have any), overlays, and I'm sure I'm selecting the right object.

Does anyone have any suggestions? The object on the right has the issue. [image]

Thank you for the help

-> file: https://pasteall.org/blend/1da817aed69346ff92e10704e13c2eef

Comment: Could you add a blend file with just the problem object in it? https://pasteall.org/blend/ Use [edit] to put the link in your question.

Comment: @HISEROD - done :)

Comment: I have no idea what the cause is, but going into either sculpt, vertex paint, or weight paint mode fixed it on my end. I'd recommend reporting this as a bug. Include the steps to reproduce the error if you can reproduce it from factory settings.

Comment: For some reason, Blender is taking your object as a Hidden one, if you press Alt + H ,that solves the problem